# How to execute psql from UNIX with variable for predicates?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I would like to know how to do the equivalent of the code below that I run in another RDBMS in Postgres.

UNIX Script:

```
call_rdbms_sql.sh
```

Content:

```
CONNDETAILS<<EOF
select col1 from table1 where col1='&ValueofCol1';
EOF
```

I execute this as:

```
UNIXPROMPT$> ksh ./call_rdbms_sql.sh col1valuepassed
```

This will be passed along to the sql script within the unix script and provide results.

I am able to setup a unix script that calls a postgres sql. This part is working fine as long as the sql script does not have any prompts to supply.

However, I want to pass values to the "Where clause".

-gv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the variable using the `psql`'s `-v` option

```
val=$1   #set the first argument to val
if [ -z $val ]           #check if it is set, exit script if it's not
then
   echo "Invalid input"
exit
fi

psql conndetails  -v ValueofCol1=$val<<EOF
select col1 from table1 where col1=:'ValueofCol1'; --use : before quoting 
                                                   --variable name
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks so much...all along I was doing ':v1', I just noticed that it should be :'v1'